# onesignal in ios for react native

Tags: ios, react-native, onesignal

I am getting error while debugingios log

[connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C94.1.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
[connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke [C94] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
TCP Conn 0x6000014c4500 Failed : error 0:61 [61]

I follow below link for setting onesignal in ios for react native but it's not woking.
however, it's working fine in android.

https://blog.logrocket.com/implement-push-notifications-react-native-onesignal/
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

Answer (score 0):

This is something else issue.
**Please run on your real iPhone device**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).